# How do I use binary arithmetic operators in combination with templates?

Tags: c++

I've written a class Number that contains only one attribute: T value. I'm currently learning about templates, so T is the data type.  What I want to achieve is doing the following sort of computation.

```
Number<int>(2) + Number<double>(1.2)
```

What I have so far can do a operation, but it fails when there are two different datatypes. So far I've written this:

```
//class template

template<class T>
class Number
{
public:

    T value;

    Number(T num1)
    {
        value = num1;
    }

    Number<T> operator + ( const Number<T> &other) const
    {
        return Number<decltype(value+other.value)> (value+other.value);
    }

};
```

It only does the arithmic operation when the datatypes are the same:

Questions:

- **Why does the program only work with the same datatypes?**

This can I answer for a part by myself. I use the line:

```
Number<T> operator + ( const Number<T> &other) const
```

So if the left handside is of type `int`. Every T becomes an `int`. I don't know how I need to change it without getting an error.

- **What do I need to fix in order to do computations with different
  datatypes?**

Edit:

A constraint is that the template may contain only one type argument

Comment: You need to declare operator + that accepts different datatypes on left and right side instead of operator that accepts Number<T> on both sides.

Comment: You need something like this: `template<class T, class U> Number<std::common_type_t<T, U>> operator+(const Number<T>&, const Number<U>&)`. Prefer `operator+` defined as a free function (maybe a `friend` one).

Comment: actually can use auto plus trailing return type to make type deduct accomplished during compile-time. like `auto operator+(const Number<T> &, const Number<S> &) -> Number<decltype(a.value + b.value)>;`, or if value is private, `a.value + b.value` can be replaced by `std::declval<T>() + std::declval<S>()`. More tidy, `std::common_type::type(c++11)/std::common_type_t(c++14)` can also be used.

Comment: @SHP where do the variables a and b come from? I forgot to mention that a contraint is that I can only use one type argument for the template. The result is that I can't use: const Number<S> anymore. What would you advice me to do? Thanks for reply!

Comment: @Nadine The template friend function don't change the way of your clasee declaration, You still have Number<T1> a; and Number<T2> b; the two template parameter comes in only in the funcion a+b.

Comment: @Nadine sorry, a and b are for Number<T> and Number<S>, and typename needs to be added. As for the answer of only one real typename (non-friend operator+ with a typename is actually 2 template), I have no clue now. The answer is a way, but not the same as what I think.

Comment: @Nadine I may have a clue, you can see the answer to see if this is what you want.

Comment: @Nadine I forgot to put it back to the form of Number, That is edited to return a corresponding Number<T> type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides declaring a friend operator+ with two template parameters as suggested, you can also place a secondary template for the member function operator+, which allows you to do casting plus.

```
template<typename T>
class Number
 {
   public:
     T value;

     Number(const T&num1)
      {
         value = num1;
      }

 template <typename X> auto operator + ( const Number<X> &other) const
      {
         auto c = this->value + other.value;
         return Number<decltype(c)> ( c );
      }
};
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    Number<int> n{2};
    Number<double> a{3.4};
    std::cout << (a+n).value << std::endl;
}
```

Or, you may use a friend function (I think that this is more symbolic consistent.)

```
template<typename T>
class Number
{
  public:

    T value;

    Number(T num1)
     {
        value = num1;
    }

   Number& operator +=( const Number<T> &other)
    {
       this->value += other.value;
       return *this;
    }
};
template <typename T1,typename T2> auto operator+(const Number<T1>&a, const Number<T2>&b)
{
    auto c = a.value + b.value;       
    return Number<decltype(c)>( c );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct Number {
    Number(T _value = T(0)) : value(_value) {}

    template <typename S>
    Number(const Number<S>& n) : value(n.value) {}

    T value;

    template <typename S>
    friend Number<S> operator+(const Number<S>& a, const Number<S>& b);
};

template <typename S>
Number<S> operator+(const Number<S>& a, const Number<S>& b) {
    return Number<S>{a.value + b.value};
}

int main() {
    std::cout << operator+<typename std::common_type<int, double>::type>(Number<int>{1}, Number<double>{1.2}).value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

this is a c++11 implementation. operator+ contains exactly one argument. I hope this is what you want.